SplToken createMint Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createMint')
   const mint = await splToken.createMint(
            connection,
            mintAuthority
            mintAuthority.publicKey, 
            null, 
            9, 
            null,
            {},
            splToken.TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        );

It is same as the splToken lib
export async function createMint(
connection: Connection,
payer: Signer,
mintAuthority: PublicKey,
freezeAuthority: PublicKey | null,
decimals: number,
keypair = Keypair.generate(),
confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

):
But I cannot run the script properly. It shows

You need to add splToken to your project in order to use it. For example, you might need to add the package to your project:
npm i @solana/spl-token`

And then import it as needed:
import * as splToken from '@solana/spl-token';


It worked when I use import {createMint} from '@solana/spl-token';
